# How to convert from Bitmap to Image and show the screenshot on the browser with VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, bitmap, base64, screenshot

I'm trying to transform from bitmap to base64 and from base64 to Image, because I want to show the screenshot on the image field named Image1. The problem is that I can't assign the value imagen to Image, it says that "Value of type  'System.Drawing.Image' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image'

```
 Imports System.Drawing
 Imports System.Windows.Forms

 Public Class fotoPrueba
   Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
    Dim base As String
    Dim imagen As Image

    base = BitmapToBase64(bmp)

    imagen = Base64ToImage(base)

    Image1 = imagen
End Sub

Public Function BitmapToBase64(ByVal image As System.Drawing.Bitmap) As String
    Dim base64 As String
    Dim memory As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    image.Save(memory, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(memory.ToArray)
    memory.Close()
    memory = Nothing
    Return base64
End Function

Function Base64ToImage(ByVal base64string As String) As System.Drawing.Image
    'Setup image and get data stream together
    Dim img As System.Drawing.Image
    Dim MS As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim b64 As String = base64string.Replace(" ", "+")
    Dim b() As Byte

    'Converts the base64 encoded msg to image data
    b = Convert.FromBase64String(b64)
    MS = New System.IO.MemoryStream(b)

    'creates image
    img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(MS)

    Return img
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: The problem is that you are mixing Windows Forms image approach with ASP.NET controls.  These are done differently. In Windows Forms you put the actual image data into the control. In ASP.NET the image control uses an URL to references the image to display (this is the ImageUrl property).  The browser then makes another request to the server for the image.  You need to write the code to satisfy that request.  [Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/436268/Previewing-Image-in-ASP-NET-Image-Control-using-VB)

Comment: Regardless of anything else, there's no conversion required.  What you're doing is like converting an apple to a fruit, a lettuce to a vegetable, a dog to an animal or a `TextBox` to a `Control`.  The `Bitmap` class inherits the `Image` class so every `Bitmap` already is an `Image`.